# How I can create section whit title of the articol taken from a website whit flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I create an application with a section were i want to show title of articol from a website in live-time. How i can do it whit flutter?

Comment: Hey, can you give some more context and also maybe some things that you have tried / had in mind ? this question is too vague

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the guidelines on how to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask